# Machine code parser for Linux

Tags: linux, assembly

I am looking for a Linux library/tool that can parse machine code instructions, preferably for the Power architecture (ppc64 or ppc64 little endian). I basically want to be able to convert a machine instruction to a readable assembly instruction string that I can process using a script.

Such functionality is obviously already part of GCC and GDB. For example, GDB can print the current assembly instruction using `x /i $pc`. Is there some underlying library that I could re-use? GCC can take an assembly instruction and generate the appropriate machine code when compiling.

Comment: so basically it's just a disassembler. Why don't you just call the available tools like objdump?

Comment: Good point, I think it can work. I would have preferred to have a library that provides a clear API that I can call at runtime. With objdump I need to: 1) get the address of instruction I want to decompile (e.g.  RIP register for the current instruction), 2) figure out what library/executable contains that instruction (probably using /proc/maps), 3) call objdump on the library/executable, parse the output, and save it in some data structure, and 4) figure out which instruction in this data structure I am actually interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/aquynh/capstone

> Capstone is a disassembly framework with the target of becoming the ultimate
>   disasm engine for binary analysis and reversing in the security community.
>
> Created by Nguyen Anh Quynh, then developed and maintained by a small community, Capstone offers some unparalleled features:
>
> - Support multiple hardware architectures: ARM, ARM64 (ARMv8), Mips, PPC, Sparc, SystemZ, XCore and X86 (including X86_64).
> - ...

---

http://mkfs.github.io/content/opdis/

> Opdis is a wrapper for the libopcodes disassembler library distributed as part of GNU `binutils`. It extends the libopcodes library by offering linear and control-flow disassembly algorithms, instruction and operand objects that are suitable for analysis, and a command-line utility to perform disassembly on arbitrary locations in a file.
>
> These features are lacking in `libopcodes` and `objdump`. The design of libopcodes makes it awkward to use for binary analysis; it assumes that disassembled instructions are going to be printed, not stored or analyzed, and therefore it invokes a callback with an `fprintf(3)` signature. The shortcomings of `objdump` are even greater: it does not support control-flow disassembly, nor does it allow the user to specify which bytes in the file to disassemble.
>
> The Opdis project consists of the `libopdis` library and the `opdis` command-line utility.
>
> ## Supported Architectures
>
> Opdis supports the disassembly of **all architectures that GNU `binutils` supports**. On most of these architectures, however, only the ASCII string for the disassembled instruction is available.

You can find more libraries [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4664/2563)

Comment: Capstone looks like what I want but it does not support 64 bit power (ppc64).